# Request to re-open this (rare, and not mine) on-topic question on the grub tag

Tags: discussion, status-declined, reopen-closed

[Grub bootloader with shared library support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25396711/grub-bootloader-with-shared-library-support) has been [on hold]ed as off-topic, and downvoted. Yet it is one one few questions actually about programming that has appeared on the tag. And it has been downvoted more heavily than the actual off-topic questions tend to be.

Other criticisms could potentially be made about the questions, but closing it as off-topic is very strange to me.

Moreover, I would like to answer it, and have stated so in the comments a few days ago - but the question remains on hold, so I am unable to.

Could someone review, and if they agree reopen it so that I can answer it, adding something other than the endless flood of off-topic posts to the tag.

Comment: Can you explain how that question pertains to programming?

Comment: It is asking about ways to load shared libraries, to extend the functionality of GRUB. That in itself makes it more on-topic than 90% of questions posted to the tag. Now it doesn't say what the intended use is of having loaded these libraries, which might make it deserving of a downvote or two if someone is feeling very picky, but does not make it off-topic.

Comment: One could argue that all questions with the [tag:grub] tag are off-topic and should be on [UNIX and Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Powerlord, "grub" by itself maybe. "grub" in the context of programming, that's probably ok.

Comment: The close reason is definitely wrong (it is about programming), but it it really worth re-opening? Is the answer going to be something other than "no, that's not possible and it doesn't even make sense"?

Comment: @AndrewMedico I'm not sure I'd consider loading something into memory on startup a *programming* question (even if it is a shared object / .so file).  It sounds more like a system operation question to me.

Comment: Now, if the question were how to write a GRUB module to load an so into memory on startup, **that** would be a programming question.

Comment: @Powerlord: what would be the intent of loading a library into GRUB if one did not intend to use it? Using it would require programming.

Comment: @Powerlord: by the same reasoning that all GRUB questions belong on http://unix.stackexchage.com/, all Linux questions would also belong there. Anyway - thank you to whoever reopened, I have now posted my answer.

Comment: Eh, it's not even a question, really.

Comment: It looks like another example of a reasonable question that people voted to close as off-topic mainly because they don't understand the subject or read it too quickly. The Q&A, as a whole, is of course much better now that there is an answer to it. Too bad some people still seem keen to vote to close...