# Something strange in voting attention to GRUB tag

Tags: discussion

So, if you look at my history on Meta, it is completely focused on the GRUB tag.

The first one was a request to act on the off-topic flags on "how do I configure my bootloader?" posts. This had wonderful short-term effect, but they are now stacking up again.

Meanwhile, the second one was last week - [Request to re-open this (rare, and not mine) on-topic question on the grub tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269736/request-to-re-open-this-rare-and-not-mine-on-topic-question-on-the-grub-tag) - requesting to reopen a question actually related to programming in the GRUB environment. It was reopened and now has a quite entertaining voting history.

Today, another question about programming in the GRUB environment - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25578024/import-user-library-to-grub2 - which if anything is a duplicate of the question I asked meta about reopening, has been "on holded" as off-topic. Within 4 hours of posting.

Meanwhile, the subsequent two questions (of the "how do I configure my bootloader?" variety) remain open, despite having been flagged as off-topic by multiple users.

I raise this as a discussion rather than another request, because something seems off in the  attention this tag is given. It keeps filling up with open off-topic posts while the on-topic ones get closed almost immediately.

Can anything be done about this situation?

Comment: that question wasn't closed by moderators but by a set of users with the [close vote privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions)

Comment: FYI: [voting status of the previous question](http://i.imgur.com/FtcOod2.png)... One more vote and it gets teleported to SuperUser.

Comment: @FrederickCheung: ah, apologies for mis-stating the situation. Question updated to reflect this.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: yeah, where it would be completely off-topic and legitimately closed.