# Erratic moderator behaviour on this question (and on the GRUB tag in general)

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

The question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27272004/grub2-error-with-multiboot-header was migrated to Unix&Linux within a couple of hours of being asked. That migration was rejected from there (after I flagged it) since the question was not related to ... Unix or Linux. Now with the question back where it belongs, it sits "closed as off-topic" - this being one of the minority of questions asked on the stackoverflow GRUB tag actually related to programming.

I flagged this for attention, and had the flag rejected as "This is still not a high-quality question". Which might have been relevant if that was the reason given for the question being closed in the first place. And if the question had been low-quality, which it is not. It contains a problem description and the relevant bits of code examples to let someone have a look at it. This is more than many questions otherwise left on the site.

I'll add that several "I tried to install an operating system and it didn't work" type questions have been sitting untouched for days and weeks.

I have previously had to [fight to get an on-topic GRUB question reopened](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269736/request-to-re-open-this-rare-and-not-mine-on-topic-question-on-the-grub-tag). What gives? Why are on-topic questions getting closed and off-topic ones left lying? What is triggering moderators to close down actual on-topic programming questions?

Comment: You have at least one point right; there is a **ton** of crap in the GRUB tag. Used up most of my close votes trying to clean up the first page.

Comment: You're right. The question never should have been migrated. It should have been closed at SO as off-topic. "I get an error" has never been a problem description that is useful, and there is no other information in the question. (You're wrong about mod bias (at least with this question, anyway It's a poorly written question that is lacking the relevant information and should have been closed.)

Comment: A different moderator had declined your flag than the one who performed the migration, which explains the inconsistency. As a third moderator, I agree that the question should not have been migrated. The good news though is that migrations can be rejected regardless of who initiated it, sending the question back to the source site.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what I was thinking when I migrated this, I made a mistake.  It was flagged by a user from Unix/Linux, I read the question and migrated it.  The mod who declined the flag asking for it to be  reopened was right and I wasn't - that'd be why this seems erratic.

Comment: The user says "After I selected my mini_os in grub2 menu, I saw an error with multiboot header.". This means that upon attempting to load the image, GRUB threw an error message at him about the image header. (and there is ) Is this the best way of posing the question - no? But it's a whole lot more specific than a superficial scan of the text might lend someone to believe. There is approximately one message in grub that fits that description, so even if it's not the exact message, it identifies the specific error condition triggered.

Comment: @KenWhite: the question is about programming. If it should be closed, which I disagree with (some people have downvoted it, and I can see why, but that's quite different from closing it and preventing people from answering it), it should be closed as "very low quality". Which I don't generally consider a question that includes the code required to produce the problem to be.

Comment: In light of your last paragraph, I'm just going to say that when I'm upset or frustrated, the first thing I do is step back and give myself some time. Time to cool off, acknowledge that whoever else is involved is human and, think about what might have happened. Then I might go address it. If I start writing and I find myself still upset, I stop and come back later. The end result is that I come off as far more rational, less insistent, and more open to things I hadn't thought of. (At least, I hope so.) I think you'd be do well to find an approach that does something similar for you.

Comment: @jpmc26: Ok, I can see how it can be read that way, but my emotional state when typing that paragraph was really more one of perplexion than one of being upset. I'll try to be more clear on that in future though, so thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @unixsmurf: No, off-topic for the reason that questions asking for debugging help have to include sufficient information (which requires a clear statement of the problem). You can see it if you have vote to close privileges by clicking on Close/Off-topic and looking at the list of reasons.

Comment: @KenWhite: No, don't have those privileges yet, but thanks for the explanation. Ok, that makes more sense then (although I still disagree, since the statement of the problem is clear to someone with enough knowledge to answer the question), but I must say that is quite semantically confusing.

Comment: @unixsmurf: Here you go: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Emphasis on **specific problem or error**, in the case of the question being discussed here.

Comment: Can you add the specific error that you saw? That's essential.

Comment: And from what I see, you've already been asked for the specific error message. It's been a week, and you still haven't added it. I'm inclined to proceed with the assumption that your Forth interpretor is spewing an error and answer based on that. :P

Comment: @KenWhite: Yes, that's part of the basic FAQ. It does not explain how a theoretical non-compliant question still related to programming becomes off-topic. As I have already said, the specific problem or error is clearly mentioned in the question ... in question.

Comment: @DonBranson: 1) Read again please, the question is not mine. 2) There is no additional information required. The specific problem or error is stated clearly in the question.

Comment: @unixsmurf a quick google of docs leads me to at least 2 errors involving multiboot: [18 20 22](http://www.uruk.org/orig-grub/errors.html).  Two of them contain the string "multiboot".  Which **specific** error isn't mentioned by the poster.

Comment: @unixsmurf - The question isn't yours, you're right. My apologies. As far as the error is concerned, I don't see it. You didn't either, according to your comment on the question - a comment which I upvoted because I agreed with your statement (and others' statements) that the specific error is important. Sorry, I'm clearly missing something, because I'm unable to reconcile your statements "@EfYak: can you add the exact error message, please?" and "The specific problem or error is stated clearly in the question."

Answer (score 27):

This question is still close-worthy, because (quoting from most appropriate close reason):

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, **a specific problem or error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

(Styling mine.)

The user says "saw error" but does not specify what error precisely occurred.

Also, the question you want reopened generally suffers from being poorly written. I would suggest when you come to Meta to ask for reopening a question that you first clean it up so that it is in correct English, correctly styled, etc. Not doing this only hurts your chances of getting the result you desire.

Comment: ++. Migrating away was wrong (and diamond mods should know better), but it's not in shape to be reopened currently.

Comment: I did not come to meta asking for the question to be reopened - I came to meta asking why slightly poorly formed questions get immediately closed down, whilst blatantly off-topic ones are left lying.

Comment: *"whilst blatantly off-topic ones are left lying"* -- Maybe they just haven't been seen by a moderator yet? I'm no mod on any SE site, but I am a Wikipedia admin and we see this kind of question all of the time: *"Why was my non-notable article deleted while this one over here remains?"* There are two answers frequently given: (1) *"Because I saw the article you created before I saw that other article."* (2) (Similar to something my parents always said...) *"We're not talking about their article, we're talking about your article."* I don't imagine the basic principles are much different here.

Comment: @cdhowie "*Because your question/answer/article is important enough that it needed to be moderated right away*". In combination with a close/delete reason that makes sense you might turn this from frustration and accusation to eagerness to become better.